# Java parallelStream not showing correct result

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was doing some performance evaluation of Java aggeragate operations to iterate over collections. I was doing an evaluation of performance `stream` and `parallelStream`. But I found that the output of `parallelStream` is wrong most of the times. For example in the following code i got wrong output from `parallelStream` more than 80% of the time:

```
    public class ParallelStreamPerformance {
    static int totaleven = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 0 ;i < 1000;i++) {
            int r = rnd.nextInt(500000);
            randomList.add(r);
        }

        long s1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        randomList.stream().filter(e -> e%2 ==0).forEach(e -> count());
        System.out.println("Even: "+totaleven);
        long e1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(e1 - s1);

        totaleven = 0;
        long s2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        randomList.parallelStream().filter(e -> e%2 ==0).forEach(e -> count());
        System.out.println("Even: "+totaleven);
        long e2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(e2 - s2);
    }
    public static void count() {
        totaleven++;
    }
}
```

My question is: Am I using `parallelStream` in a wrong way? Is there any way to ensure the correctness of `parallelStream`.
Thanks

Comment: Your benchmarking methodology is worse than worthless; it will give you answers, but they'll be wrong.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Thanks @BrianGoetz

Comment: When your actual question is about getting a wrong result, you shouldn’t clutter it with irrelevant benchmark stuff. Your code could have be shortened to ten lines and the prose about you doing a “performance evaluation” is obsolete as well. When your code doesn’t work correctly, you don’t need to measure its performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code having issue with `count()` method. As `parallelStream` will try to perform task concurrently. This method should be `synchronized` or you can make `totaleven` as Atomtic Integer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes using synchronized method solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: So now your code is _correct_, but it is unlikely that the parallel code will be faster than the sequential (which is the only reason to use parallelism), since the threads will spend all their time waiting for a lock.  What you want to do is use `count()` or `reduce()` rather than incrementing a shared mutable counter.  This is easier to get right (no synchronization needed) and more parallel-friendly.

Comment: @BrianGoetz: perhaps it was a design mistake to add `forEach` to the Stream API…

Comment: @Holger We actually did discuss that, since the only purpose of any stream operation whose behavior parameters don't return anything is to do side-effects.  But realistically, we would have (and should have) been laughed out of the room had we done so; that would have just been hiding our heads in the sand.  (And then people would have just coopted some other terminal operation and done their side-effects inside, say, a `map()` call, and collected into an empty sink to simulate `forEach()`.)  For better or worse, side-effects are part of Java.  At best we can discourage them.

Comment: @BrianGoetz: perhaps, a not-so-easy-to-find name had helped, e.g. see how much the existence of `forEachOrdered` gets ignored…

Comment: @Holger It's easy to say "you should have done", and certainly any given complaint can be addressed by a "you should have done" argument, but there's a missing step to this: imagine what other complaints, that are not made now, would have been made in the world where we'd done that.  In this case, I think the complaints about "why is such an important operation given such a non-obvious name" would have been overwhelming.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the forEach to increment a counter you can use the terminal operation [Stream:count](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--)

For example

```
totaleven = randomList.stream().filter(e -> e % 2 ==0).count();
totaleven = 0;
totaleven = randomList.parallelStream().filter(e -> e % 2 ==0).count();
```

totaleven would need to be changed to data type long or casting applied.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with parallel stream result? If it is too small then most likely you have problem with `totaleven++` as it is not thread safe. Use AtomicInteger or any other thread safe solution.